# li type won't display

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following css:

```
ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}
ul.square li {
padding-left:20px;
list-style:square;
}
```

and the following Html structure:

```
<ul class="square">
<li>blah blah blah</li>
</ul>
```

the list comes up with no padding and no leading square. How can I fixed this issue?

Comment: let the `list-style:square;` on `ul` and use `margin-left` instead of `padding-left` [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2dajjnt/2/)

Comment: Also note that `list-style` **is a shorthand**

Comment: I don't want it to appear on every list, just this one. Hence, I was trying to create a separate ul.square grouping in CSS. See my initial coding. If I put it on ul it will affect every list on this very large website. I have tried ul .square ul.square, etc. Neither the square nor the left padding/margin show either way

Comment: _“If I put it on ul it will affect every list”_ – no, it will not – because you of course keep the class selector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This only works with `ol` (tried it with `ul` and it doesn't work).  Could not get the square to work with `ul` with any solution provided here or elsewhere.  But at least this solution does add the margin/indentation.  Thank you for all of the help.

In CSS:

```
ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
li {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}
ol.margin {
padding:0;
margin: 0; /* reset the margin */
margin-left:20px; /* then add yours */
}
```

then in the HTML doc

```
<ol id="margin">
<li>blah</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Of course it works fine inside `ul` elements as well – you just have to do it correctly (and that starts by paying attention to @Krii’s comment about `list-style` being a shorthand. It makes `list-style-position` take the default value `outside` – and _that_ doesn’t work with the margin/padding combination you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Just use margin, instead of padding –>  [Demo](http://codepen.io/isaacminogue/pen/LNObZq)

```
ul.square {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0; /* reset the margin */
  margin-left:20px; /* then add yours */
  list-style: square;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to appear on every list, just this one.  Hence, I was trying to create a separate ul.square grouping in CSS. See my initial coding.  If I put it on ul it will affect every list on this very large website.  I have tried ul .square ul.square, etc.  Neither the square nor the left padding/margin show either way.

Comment: Hey @Frank, it should work with `ul.square` , check the demo again to see.

Comment: Yes, I agree and can confirm that what Isaac has here is the best and simplest way to do this.

Comment: I wish it did.  I copied his solution verbatim, and used it with:  <ul class="square">
            <li>blah</li><li>blah</li></ul> but it is not getting the padding or the square.  I read somewhere else in stackoverflow where they were having the same issue.  It conflicts with the ul settings and even though ul.square *should* override those settings.  It doesn't.  I was hoping somebody had found a solution to that.

Comment: using ol instead of ul and id=square instead of class=square, I can get the margin to work.